# Как проверить существование видео youtube?

Tags: java, android

Например, есть поле ввода для ссылки, пользователь вводит и нажимает добавить, и если видео существует, то возврощает true

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: У Youtube есть свое API https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно сделать так.

```
private static Boolean checker(String YoutubeUrl){
        //Строка на странице, которая указывает на статус видео. Есть оно или нет
        String ok = "playabilityStatus\\\":{\\\"status\\\":\\\"OK\\\"";
        try {

            URL url = new URL(YoutubeUrl);
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();


            try(
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8");
                    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(reader)
            ){
                String line = "";
                while((line=buf.readLine()) != null){
                    if(line.contains(ok)){
                        return true;
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```